# How can I make a file upload field be consistent during edits with Elixir/Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my form template I have this snippet:

```
  <%= label f, :event_banner_image %>
  <%= file_input f, :event_banner_image %>
  <%= error_tag f, :event_banner_image %>
```

Creating a new event (from "/events/new") with one of these images works fine, but then when I go to edit the event the file input is empty. In a way, of course it is because the server doesn't know about the local path to the file that was uploaded. Even so, I wonder if I'm missing out on a way to make this a better experience.

Answer (score 2):

Working with images is quite tricky. How I went about such a case is by manually extracting the image path from the `%Phoenix.HTML.Form{}` struct, the `f` in your code.

```
<%= img_tag f.data.banner_image_path, class: ""  %>
```

It is much easier if it's just one image such that reuploading replaces the previous one.
You can find more about the [structure of phoenix HTML form here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html)